# Why the weight paint for my bone is mirroring on the other arm?

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, weight-paint-mode

I have selected the right biceps and the weight paint is only there.

[image]
But if I select the right Middle1 finger, I see changes in the weight paint on both arms.
[image]
So when I try to move the right arm it will also move some part of the left arm.
[image]
I am new to blender and rigging. I tried going in Weight Paint mode and erase from the other arm but It did not work. But if I erase from the right Middle finger it will erase on the other arm.

What can I do?

[SOLUTION] I had, for my arms the mirror modifier unapplied. When I applied it, I could edit the other hand too.

Comment: Are you using a mirror modifier?

Comment: Take a look at the top right of your 3D view and see if symmetry on X is not enabled

Answer (score 1):

In Weight Paint Mode, there is an option to turn on X, Y, or Z symmetry. So if the painting is mirrored, make sure the symmetry is turned off.

Comment: The symmetry was turned off. But I had for my arms mesh, or what is called, the mirror modifier. And that stopped me from decolouring the left arm. Now that I applied it I could color or decolour the left arm too. I don't know if it made sense what I just said, but thanks for helping.